# SaltStack client.cmd outputter

Tags: python, salt-stack

I am using python/flask/salt api code to create a salt stack web gui of some kind. Example state check Code and output on page:-

```
@app.route('/salty')
def salty():
    user = {'nickname': 'Human'}  # fake user
    client = salt.client.LocalClient()
    retinfo = client.cmd('linuxservers', 'state.sls', ['linuxservers.bashbug-check'],          expr_form='nodegroup')
    return render_template("salt.html",
                       title='Salt',
                       user=user,
                       cmd=retinfo)
```

The dict Output looks like so on my webpage:-

```
{'testserver1': {'cmd_|-locate-bashbug_|-locate-bashbug_|-script': {'comment': "Command 'locate-bashbug' run", '__run_num__': 0, 'changes': {'pid': 431, 'retcode': 0, 'stderr': '', 'stdout': 'i hate colours'}, 'name': 'locate-bashbug', 'result': True}},
```

The thing is, I wan't it to show output as it does from the cmd line bin, which is the highstate outputted style as far as I know. I am probably still a little confused on the easiest way to code this in using the salt api.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: from your cmd line output, wouldn't it be what's it your `stdout`:`i hate colors`?

Comment: well yes I suppose the k:v stdout is what I wan't but I really wanted the more verbose output as provided by the binary default outputter. If I run the same state check from the cmdline on the same salt master/client it gives me a nicer output.

Comment: I haven't used SaltStack so I cannot comment, but from what I read your `stdout` should be a direct `sys.stdout`. Could you paste an image and see what's your desire output?

Comment: Just hit the same bump you did @Pash ... If I find a solution for more easily parsing what comes back from the minion when running state.sls via the python API I'll give you an update ... Just so you know you're not alone .. and If you have an update please post it :)